# Firebase hosting blank page

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment

I tried using firebase hosting since I'm using the database already. I followed the step provided, but when I click to link for my deployed app it comes up empty. Any solutions?

ng serve/local host:
[image]
deployed version: [image]

Tried re-deploying multiple time but sometime would come up with firebase deployment screen and not my actual app. And when I tried replacing the index.html file, I get the blank screen above.

Comment: Opening [the URL from your screenshot](https://angular-fitness-tracker-a6e8c.web.app/) and inspecting the element shows that the Javascript files for your are not being included. This is why the app doesn't work

Comment: I see, but how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer this without more information about your app and how you are building it for the deployment. Can you edit your question and provide the commands you use to deploy the app?

Comment: After committing everything I did : ng build --configuration build, npm i firebase-tools, firebase login, firebase init, firebase deploy

Comment: Do you have `build` defined as a configuration in your `angular.json` file? Maybe your build command should be just `ng build` instead?

Comment: I just tried ng build and I did the rest of the steps. Now in my dist folder appeared with an index.html document with firebase documentation in there. Do I replace it with my index.html file?

Comment: `ng build` should create a dist folder with all of the Angular code inside it prepared for deployment. I'm not sure why the index.html file has firebase documentation in it... Maybe the firebase command overwrites the files?